# lodash isNil is not a function

Tags: node.js, lodash

I am receiving the error like "TypeError: __.isNil is not a function". My code is as follows:

```
var __ = require('lodash')
var li_stored_data;

test(function (result) {

    li_stored_data = result;
})

function test(cb) {
    var testobj ={};
    testobj.valu = 'bhr';
    cb(testobj);
}

if(__.isNil(li_stored_data))
{
    console.log('its empty')
}
```

Comment: isNil was introduced in lodash 4.0.0. What version are you using? https://lodash.com/docs#isNil

Answer (score 1):

After updating lodash version, the issue was solved.